# mySQL query to return totals of matching rows

Tags: mysql

This might be the first time I've ever had to ask a question!  Usually find things already answered!  anyhoo... here goes...

recordset has a job_id column, there might be 20 rows for that job_id, a numerical value posted in another column for each row.  I'd like to be able to query the table where I can sum together all the numbers for each job_id.  the resultant recordset will have however many rows, one row for each job_id, and a column with all the numerical values totalled for that job_id (hope that makes sense!)

Comment: Take a look at `sum` and `group by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
SELECT job_id,SUM(numerical value) 
FROM table_name 
group by job_id
```

hope this help you

best regards

Comment: Help??  it absolutely hit it square on the head and makes such obvious sense!  
mucho thanks!

Comment: absolutely!  took me a second to work out how to that!  hopefully done now.  need to post another question now for the next bit I want to LEFT JOIN if that's possible!\

Comment: could you provide me some details for the tables and description about needed query??

Comment: this query is to pull all the costs in for a job, in another table there is a list of jobs, job_id = ID in the second table so I would like to JOIN some of the fields from the jobs table to the result  of the SUM query.  so something like:

SELECT job_id,SUM(final_invoice_cost)
FROM invoices
GROUP BY job_id LEFT JOIN master_jobs ON master_ID = invoices.job_id

Comment: try this SELECT job_id,SUM(final_invoice_cost) FROM master_jobs LEFT JOIN invoices  ON master_ID = invoices.job_id GROUP BY job_id

Comment: Brings in the same results but has 1 extra blank row at the beginning?

Comment: SELECT job_id,SUM(final_invoice_cost) FROM invoices LEFT JOIN master_jobs  ON invoices.job_id =master_ID GROUP BY job_id

Comment: same result but this time it doesn't have the blank first row, so the results are the same as the original SUM query!

Comment: fields I would like are client_forename, client_surname, deposit and date.  once I see how the query works I will probably be able to change these.  I Really appreciate your help!

Comment: SELECT job_id,client_forename,SUM(final_invoice_cost) FROM invoices LEFT JOIN master_jobs ON invoices.job_id =master_ID GROUP BY job_id,client_forename

Comment: when adding any new field from invoices to the query you need to put it in group by statment

Comment: BRILLIANT!  Thank you ever so much.  Helped me out massively!

Comment: yup.  is that a case of just click the up arrow (sorry! new to this!)

Comment: you didn't voted up my answer, but you removed accepting my answer . just click on the right icon and up arrow

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY to group results by job_id and make the sum of numeric values for each group.

```
select job_id, sum(numeric_val) sum_numeric_val
from mytable
group by job_id
```